# Как изменить шрифт Listview?

Tags: android, listview, шрифты

Всем привет! Второй день подряд пытаюсь найти место в коде для заученной уже наизусть комбинации команд:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_prop);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "segoe_print.ttf"); 
textView.setTypeface(font);
```

Итак, есть простой xml-файл для меню с ListView menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       ...           
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/menu_top"
       ...
       </LinearLayout>          
<ListView 
          android:id="@+id/ListView_Menu"
          ...>
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Есть файл под Items и стрелочку в конце каждого пункта меню menu_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    ...    
 <LinearLayout 
    ...      
    <TextView
android:id="@+id/menu_prop"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="test string"/>
    </LinearLayout>    
 <LinearLayout 
    ...    
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Есть java-файл для меню Main_menu.java:

```
public class Main_menu extends Activity {       
    private ListView menuList;      
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);            
        Calculator calc_data[] = new Calculator[]
                {   new Calculator("К1", R.drawable.arrow),
                    new Calculator("К2", R.drawable.arrow),
                    new Calculator("К3", R.drawable.arrow),
                    new Calculator("К4", R.drawable.arrow)
                };            
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.menu_item, calc_data);     
        menuList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView_Menu); 
        menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

Есть файл с адаптером CustomAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Calculator> {   
    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    Calculator data[] = null; 
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Calculator[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    } 
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        CalculatorHolder holder = null;        
        if(view == null)
        {LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false); 
            holder = new CalculatorHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_prop);
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgArrow); 
            view.setTag(holder);        }
        else
        {holder = (CalculatorHolder)view.getTag();        } 
        Calculator calculator = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(calculator.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(calculator.icon); 
        return view;    }
        static class CalculatorHolder
    {   ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

И есть еще какой-то вспомогательный адаптер - я пока не разобрался, как он работает )) Calculator.java:

```
public class Calculator {
    public String title;
    public int icon;
    public Calculator(){
        super();
    } 
    public Calculator(String title, int icon) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;        
    }
}
```

Теперь вопрос - как мне изменить шрифт у элементов меню ListView? Пробовал в разные места файла CustomAdapter вставлять строку
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), null);
но каждый раз приложение вылетает. Именно из-за этой строки. Без нее все работает.

Ответ дан, он помог, тему можно закрывать. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Елки зеленые, получилось! Спасибо большое Suvitruf!

Comment: @Rm1, не за что (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать свои кастомные элементы.
Не так давно писал [статью](http://suvitruf.ru/2013/10/22/3320/), как юзать кастомные шрифты.

Вот пример своего кастомного элемента:

```
public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
//    private static final String TAG = "TextView";

    public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont); 
        a.recycle(); 
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) { 
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
//          LOG.d("asset = "+asset); 
            tf = Typefaces.get(getContext(), asset);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e("Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);
        return true;
    }
}
```

В attr.xml ещё дописать:

```
<declare-styleable name="TextViewPlus">
    <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

В слое в .xml добавить это:

```
xmlns:MY="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ваш_пакет"
```

Юзать так:

```
    <пакет.TextViewPlus
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"                          android:layout_height="match_parent"                    
MY:customFont = "мой_шрифт.ttf"                     
    />
```

Comment: сделал все как описано, но в `class TextViewPlus` подчеркивает красным `Typefaces` (`cannot find symbol variable Typefaces`) в строке `tf = Typefaces.get(getContext(), asset);`. Подскажи, что это может быть за ошибка?

Comment: @Pollux импортнуть надо пакет.

Comment: Подскажи, что за пакет?

Comment: @Pollux вроде `import   android.graphics.Typeface;`